# Adding instrumentation to perform a null check in LLVM IR when dereferencing a pointer

Tags: c++, if-statement, null, llvm, code-generation

I am writing an LLVM pass where I want to print out the values of function arguments. I am only focusing on integers and pointers to integers (which will also involve `char`, I guess but that is not a problem for my purposes). If the argument is a pointer, I want to dereference it and print the value that is pointed to by the pointer. To guard against null pointers, in normal C code I can do:

```
function foo(int* bar, int** baz) {
  if (bar) {
    printf("bar: %d\n", *bar);
  }

  if (baz) {
    printf("baz: %d\n", **baz);
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do something similar in LLVM? Currently I am doing the following to actually load the value by dereferencing the pointer. I am working off a `StoreInst` that LLVM generates to set up the values of function parameters. For example, for the function above, there would be something like:

```
%bar.addr = alloca i32*, align 8
%baz.addr = alloca i32**, align 8
store i32* %bar, i32** %bar.addr, align 8
store i32** %baz, i32*** %baz.addr, align 8
```

So using that `StoreInst`, I am doing something like this:

```
auto *value = store->getValueOperand();
auto *type = value->getType();
int indirection = 0;
while (type->isPointerTy()) {
  indirection++;
  type = type->getPointerElementType();
}

Value* load = value;
unsigned int bitWidth = type->getIntegerBitWidth(); // I have already verified earlier on that
                                                    // this eventually resolves to an IntegerType
while (indirection > 0) {
  load = (indirection == 1) ? irb.CreateLoad(getIntegerType(bitWidth), load)
                            : irb.CreateLoad(getPointerToIntegerType(indirection - 1, bitWidth), load);
  --indirection;
}

value = load;
```

The `getIntegerType` is just a convenience function that returns an `IntegerType` with the provided bit-width and using the current LLVM context. The `getPointerToIntegerType` function is as follows:

```
Type* getPointerToIntegerType(int indirection, unsigned int bitWidth) {
  Type* type = getIntegerType(bitWidth);
  while (indirection > 0) {
    type = PointerType::get(type, 0);
    --indirection;
  }

  return type;
}
```

Using this I get the following `load` instructions after the `store` instructions (I've omitted some stuff from the `call` instructions for brevity):

```
store i32* %bar, i32** %bar.addr, align 8
%1 = load i32, i32* %bar
call void (i8, ...) @__print_argument_value(...)

store i32** %baz, i32*** %baz.addr, align 8
%2 = load i32*, i32** %baz
%3 = load i32, i32* %2
call void (i8, ...) @__print_argument_value(...)
```

This works perfectly as long as the pointers are not null. Is there an easy way I can generate IR to guard the call to `__print_argument_value`? I did write out an explicit `if (bar) { ... }` and a `if (baz) { ... }` and then looked at the generated IR to see how LLVM generates it. I saw that it performs an `icmp ne` of the pointer (the `.addr` variable) against `null`. Then if the result is true, it breaks to a label `if.then` where it calls the function, or else to the label `if.end` which skips over it.

The problem is that I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how I can generate IR like that from my LLVM pass. Are there any examples I can look at? I did look up the documentation but I still can't figure out how to put the pieces together using the LLVM API even though I know what the IR *should* look like. I saw some documentation about to PHI nodes which I don't see in my IR from the explicit null check, but I am not entirely clear on what they are and how they would help me.

PS: Please excuse any weirdness in the C/C++ code; I usually program in Java.

Comment: I suppose you meant `if (baz && *baz)`?

Comment: What's exact problem? You first create `BasicBlock`'s and then a `br` instruction, like here: https://github.com/HikariObfuscator/Core/blob/master/BogusControlFlow.cpp#L312

Comment: @arrowd thanks let me take a look at that example.